# Does not load js and css from CDN URL incase of secure pages with protocol "https"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, cdn

I am implementing the code in .net MVC for loading js and css from CDN URL and it works good with protocol "http". But if site is Secure with SSL then js and css does not from CDN url on secure pages.

What should I do to resolve this?

Please give me suggestions.

Thank You.

Comment: Are you saying that if both your webpage and CSS/JS are coming from a HTTPS source, it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is running over HTTPS then your CSS and Javascript files must also come from a secure server. This is a security measure to prevent things like man-in-the-middle attacks.

So the answer is to make sure your CSS & JS files are also served using HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you David for your response. But I request you to look into my question again, I have edited the question. Please Advise.